# Insert Line Break in excel between subreports in JasperReports

Tags: excel, jasper-reports, subreport

I have a requirement where I need to add an empty line between every sub report in Excel. Can you please let me know how can I do that?
I am using *JasperReports 4.5.1*.

Answer (score 0):

If You have a single subReport in a details band which is executed for each row and you want empty line between each execution, just make details band higher then the subReport element.

If you have multiple subReports in a single details band and you want empty lines between them, leave empty space between them in report designer.